# How do I get Bluetooth ID of a Bluetooth device in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, bluetooth, windows-phone-8

I want to develop an application in which I want get Bluetooth Id of different device.

My concept is when I start my application at that time I want get Bluetooth id of different devices on load event of first form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WP7 doesn't support bluetooth APIs for 3rd party developers. WP8 does. WP8 can iterate over all **paired** bluetooth devices. You can read more about what types of Bluetooth Developer scenarios are supported on WP8 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490318/possible-keys-for-alternateidentities-in-peerfinder).  For an example of how to get a collection of all devices paired to WP8 see [this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What%27s_new_in_Windows_Phone_8#Bluetooth:_Phone_to_device).

Comment: :thanks but wp7 have bluetooth.(i.e)nokia lumia 710 provide facality to search device in built application. so this thing i can not apply on my application?

Comment: :I just want search bluetooth device through my application and get bluetooth id.Nothing else so its not possible?

Comment: No, WP7 does not expose 3rd party developers API for bluetooth.