# "The requested allocation size was too large" when calling PeerFinder.Start();

Tags: c#, windows-8, bluetooth, windows-store-apps

When executing the following lines in my Windows Store App project

```
PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:Paired"] = "";
PeerFinder.Start();
```

I get the following error:

> > The requested allocation size was too large (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080011 (MEM_E_INVALID_SIZE))

Which is the problem there? How do I solve it?

Comment: What's your goal with this code? I think the only alternate identity available for you on Windows 8 was something like PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["WindowsPhone"] = <phone app id GUID> for app-to-app pairing (cf. [PeerFinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.peerfinder.alternateidentities.aspx) doc and [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.peerfinder.alternateidentities.aspx).

Comment: So, it is not possible to connect to paired bluetooth devices the same way it can be done in Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that it is not possible to connect a Windows Store app to a Bluetooth device the same way it can be done in Windows Phone 8.

While `PeerFinder` uses Bluetooth in Windows Phone 8, Wi-Fi Direct is used in Winsdows Store apps for peer discovery. That said, it seems the scenario of connecting a Windows Store app to a Bluetooth device is not currently possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing App to Device, `PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:Paired"] = "";` is correct. Look at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490318/possible-keys-for-alternateidentities-in-peerfinder).

The solution to you receiving this message `“The requested allocation size was too large”`is to remove `PeerFinder.Start();`. It should work.

I'm also working on Windows Store App for Bluetooth. But so far, it's not working. The method `FindAllPeerAsync` kept giving me null - nothing is found. If you managed to get Bluetooth working, please advice me and well.